# Where does MongoDB Atlas fit in my nodejs app?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have an express app using MongoDB up and running locally. I am looking at options to deploy and wasn't clear on how MongoDB atlas fit in. I planning on just deploying the express app and database to an ec2 instance. Is that alright? Or do I need a separate instance for mongo to run on? MongoDB Atlas offers M2, M5, M10 etc. as options for nodes. I am very new at backend and want to know if those would be separate from my EC2 instance or if those would be my EC2 instance running my express app for clients to connect to as well.

Answer (score 3):

Mongo Atlas is a standalone hosted MongoDB instance. It's a separate server, or typically a cluster of several servers, that only runs MongoDB. You'd run your Express app on an EC2 instance and have it talk over the network to the Mongo Atlas instance on another server.

The advantage is that you don't have to worry about installing or handholding Mongo, about configuring a redundant Mongo cluster, about upgrades or backups. Generally, separating the database server from the application server also means easier longterm maintenance of both. If your Express server doesn't store any data itself, then it is entirely disposable in case of emergencies, while you can be assured* that the critical data stored in your database is well cared for.

* As far as your contract with Atlas stipulates that the data is being cared for…